# Add elements to an array with a probability

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, random

So I am building a list in Python, for example, let us say the first 100 integers, but I do need all the 100 integers but only a sample lets say 3.

```
import random 

def f():
    list_ = []
    for i in range(100):
        list_.append(i)
    return list_

def g(list_,k):
     return random.sample(list_, k)

print(g(f(),3))

>>>[50, 92, 6]
```

Now can I get away with not building the whole list in the first place, but directly build the sample, maybe by adding a probability with which elements get added to the list in `f()`

Because if I am building a huge list which does not integers numbers but some other objects, this approach could be costly, in terms of memory and computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def random_no_dups_k_of_n(k, n):
    res = list(range(k))
    for i in range(k, n):
        v = random.randint(0, i) # this is 0-i inclusive
        if v == i:
            ir = random.randint(0,k-1)
            res[ir] = i
    return res
```

What's happening here:  it's a telescoping product.  Each element from `0` to `k-1` starts out having a `k/k` chance of being selected.  After 1st iteration `k` has `1/(k+1)` chance of getting selected, while **all** others (not just remaining, but all) have a `(k-1)/k * k/(k+1) = (k-1)/(k+1)` chance of getting selected.  After 2nd iteration, `k+1` has a `1/(k+2)` chance of getting selected, while all the others have a `(k-1)/(k+1) * (k+1)/(k+2) = (k-1)/(k+2)` chance of getting selected.  And so on.  In the end, each number will have a `k/n` chance of getting selected.

Actually, I just saw that you can just do `random.sample(range(n), k)`.  I just assumed it wasn't available.

***EDIT***: I got the probabilities reversed above.  The correct version should be:

```
def random_no_dups_k_of_n(k, n):
    res = list(range(k))
    for i in range(k, n):
        v = random.randint(0, i) # this is 0-i inclusive
        if v < k:
            ir = random.randint(0,k-1)
            res[ir] = i
    return res
```

Each element from `0` to `k-1` starts out having a `k/k` chance of being selected.  After 1st iteration `k` has `k/(k+1)` chance of getting selected, while **all** others (not just remaining, but all) have a `k/k*((k-1)/k * k/(k+1) + 1(k+1) = k/(k+1)` chance of getting selected.  After 2nd iteration, `k+1` has a `k/(k+2)` chance of getting selected, while all the others have a `k/(k+1)*((k-1)/k * k/(k+2) + 2/(k+2))= k/(k+2)` chance of getting selected.

And this actually does collapse all the calculations to give each element a `k/(k+m)` chance after `m`th step.

Comment: Actually, I am not dealing with integers but objects of a certain class, so ``range(n)`` will not work there. But your solution is novel and works. Thanks.

Comment: @Vajjhala, please, see the the correction. It's a small bug in the program, but a big change in probabilities.